# Blocking a shortcut in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, xml

How can I block the "*Ctrl*" and "*-*" shortcut in Windows 10. This shortcut in the sales application that I deal with on a daily basis creates a hidden US special character that breaks the structure of the XML file that is exported to the accounting program. It happens such a situation in the points that I supports, ladies want to get the bottom underscore "_" and instead of *Shift* - they will use *Ctrl* - I know, this is stupid, but I have no influence on it.

I cannot lock all functions with the Ctrl key as they are used frequently. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to set up/overwrite a local (app-specific) keyboard shortcut. I would suggest using [AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/tags/autohotkey/info) to do so.

Try something along these lines: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm

```
$^-::
if WinActive("ahk_class mySalesApplication")
    return  ; i.e. do nothing, which causes Control- to do nothing in the specified app.
Send ^-
return
```

Comment: Thank you. The program works perfectly. I only modified the script: instead of ahk_class I used the ahk_exe function. In the program I use, I have several locations where a shortcut can be used. Windows Spy in the application informed me of several different class. The ahk_exe function will block the shortcut for the entire application.

Comment: @milk Nice. I am glad this worked out so well; thanks for mentioning `ahk_exe`, that's probably what most people want to use.